# Why react changes the class names dynamically inside snapshots

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme, styled-components

When I run test cases in react js, the snapshots are failing every time for different system. As it is generating some random classname and some random row-index value.

```
- Snapshot
+ Received

@@ -6,11 +6,11 @@
      <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
        <div
          align="center"
-         class="WithStyles(ForwardRef(Typography))-root-1"
+         class="WithStyles(ForwardRef(Typography))-root-104"
          color="error"
        >
          This is a test error
        </div>
      </div>



<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
            <hr
-             class="MuiDivider-root WithStyles(ForwardRef(Divider))-root-1"
+             class="MuiDivider-root WithStyles(ForwardRef(Divider))-root-141"
            />
          </div>



<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
        <pre>
          <code
-           class="sc-jKJlTe cGvMyR"
+           class="sc-dxgOiQ cbLIqq"
          >
            No data
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is using Mui (Material UI) components. And in MUI classes are generated dynamically at compile time. So either assign you're own class name to an element or use role or id attribute instead.